# Jquery zoom plugin to zoom a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

i've been searching a little bit on internet for a jquery plugin letting me to zoom an image.

I found many of them, doing it in several ways, my favorites are those ones that zoom the image in a separate area and not directly the original image.

ex http://i-like-robots.github.io/EasyZoom/ (one of the many)

But all these plugins seems to work directly on img tag instead i would like to zoom a div with src attribute referring to an image. (The html main structure is given so i cannot change it that much).

Do you know any plugin doing it or do you know how i could do it?
(would be better if t works also ojn IE8-9, even if it's not a must)
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Zoomooz plugins](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/) there are free and simple to use

See [Simple Zoom Demo with Zoomooz on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mVf8Z/52/)

```
$("#zoom").click(function () {
    $(this).zoomTo({
        targetsize: 1.0,
        root: $(".container")
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there any Other Plugins?

Comment: Thanks! The plugin works, but the fiddle demo doesn't, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think zoomooz will do what you're looking for.
http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Answer (score 1):

here is a few list of jQuery plugins try it.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/jquery-plugins-for-containerdiv-zoom/

Answer (score 1):

[Panzoom](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/) can do it as well. Give it a try.